# Dockerfile build fails all of a sudden

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, jupyterhub, docker-build

I'm trying to resolve build problems when running commands to build below `dockerfile`,
errors for example I get:
1.

```
/bin/sh: 1: /opt/conda/bin/pip: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c wget -q https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.2.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /tmp/miniconda.sh  &&     echo 'd0c7c71cc5659e54ab51f2005a8d96f3 */tmp/miniconda.sh' | md5sum -c - &&     bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -f -b -p /opt/conda &&     /opt/conda/bin/conda install --yes -c conda-forge       python=3.5 sqlalchemy tornado jinja2 traitlets requests pip pycurl       nodejs configurable-http-proxy &&     /opt/conda/bin/pip install --upgrade pip &&     rm /tmp/miniconda.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

2.
  When trying to comment the problematic part we get another issue with `npm` such as:
  `/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found`

Any idea what's going on here?

**Dockerfile**

```
# Copyright (c) Jupyter Development Team.
# Distributed under the terms of the Modified BSD License.

FROM debian:jessie
MAINTAINER Jupyter Project <jupyter@googlegroups.com>

# install nodejs, utf8 locale, set CDN because default httpredir is unreliable
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN REPO=http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org && \
    echo "deb $REPO/debian jessie main\ndeb $REPO/debian-security jessie/updates main" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get -y install wget locales git bzip2 &&\
    /usr/sbin/update-locale LANG=C.UTF-8 && \
    locale-gen C.UTF-8 && \
    apt-get remove -y locales && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# install Python + NodeJS with conda
RUN wget -q https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.2.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /tmp/miniconda.sh  && \
    echo 'd0c7c71cc5659e54ab51f2005a8d96f3 */tmp/miniconda.sh' | md5sum -c - && \
    bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -f -b -p /opt/conda && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda install --yes -c conda-forge \
      python=3.5 sqlalchemy tornado jinja2 traitlets requests pip pycurl \
      nodejs configurable-http-proxy && \
    /opt/conda/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    rm /tmp/miniconda.sh
ENV PATH=/opt/conda/bin:$PATH

EXPOSE 8000

RUN mkdir -p /src/jupyterhub
WORKDIR /src/jupyterhub

ADD . /src/jupyterhub


RUN npm install --unsafe-perm && \
    pip install . && \
    rm -rf $PWD ~/.cache ~/.npm

ADD . /src/jupyterhub        
LABEL org.jupyter.service="jupyterhub"

CMD ["jupyterhub"]
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell what part causes this error. Can you try to use multiple RUN statements, without the && between them? That will help to isolate the problem. (when the problem is solved you'll be able to re-merge all RUNs in one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest `pip` package hosted by conda forge is `noarch/pip-20.0.2-py_2.tar.bz2` and it has the `bin` folder missing hence calling `/opt/conda/bin/pip` will give `/opt/conda/bin/pip: not found` error.

I would suggest enforcing the versions of the packages to prevent updated versions causing build error, this will achieve deterministic builds in different machines which saves time on having to figure out what version change is causing the error.

In order to get `pip` properly, amending the `Dockerfile` with the below should do the trick:

```
RUN wget -q https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.2.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /tmp/miniconda.sh  && \
    echo 'd0c7c71cc5659e54ab51f2005a8d96f3 */tmp/miniconda.sh' | md5sum -c - && \
    bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -f -b -p /opt/conda && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda install --yes -c conda-forge \
      python=3.5 sqlalchemy tornado jinja2 traitlets requests pip=18.0=py35_1001 pycurl \
      nodejs configurable-http-proxy && \
    /opt/conda/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    rm /tmp/miniconda.sh
```